# Using Mac OS Framework libs from XE2 linker

Tags: macos, c++builder

I want to use the embarcadero XE2 compiler to generate an application for the Mac OS.
I tested the XE2 C++ compiler using the example [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/OpenGL_Multicolor_Tetrahedron_%28C++%29).

This example explains how to add a mac os framework (openGL & GLUT) in
order to tell the XE2 linker to link with the libs in these frameworks.

This example works very well on my PC (Win7 connected to Mac OS SL 10.6.6).

then I tried an dexample in order to use the Acceleralte framework
(Blas & lapack libs) :

I created a console App & added the Accelerate framework :
I set the path on remote machine to "/System/Library/Frameworks", the file
mask to "Accelerate", and the path type "Framework".

the example I used is "File1.cpp" copied from the example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/AccelerateFrameworkData/_index.html):

The project compiles well but I got a link error: [ILINK32 Error] "ilink32" exited with code 3.

I tried adding the libBLAS.dylib & libLAPACK.dylib to the linker additionnal options but it does not work.

I has 2 questions :

1-Does the XE2 for mac os is limited to a certain number of mac os frameworks ?

2- Can we generate a xcode project (like for the iOs target) and build the mac os project on the mac using Xcode ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example by removing the "Accelerate" framework from the project options.
I copied manually the libBLAS.dylib & libLAPACK.dylib from the mac and put them on my PC.
I also copied the "Accelerate" header file to my PC and added their directory to include path of XE2 compiler.